# Cannot reach TFS website through internet

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, port-forwarding, team-foundation-server

I installed the TFS on a Windows Server 2012 machine, the URL of the TFS is for example http://appsrv:10001/tfs. I can open the website if I'm in the same domain as the server but if I try to open it through the internet it does not work. I know the external IP of the router which is for example 100.100.100.100 and when I browse the URL http://100.100.100.100:10001/tfs it asks for the user name and password what I set during the installation of TFS. After I type in the proper credentials the URL in the browser changes to appsrv:10001/tfs. So the port forwarding is working and the firewall does not block me but the browser sais that "Cannot find the DNS address of 'appsrv' server". It is something with IIS but I don't know what to do.

Comment: External clients can't resolve the internal name of TFS. You need to configure an external/public URL in TFS for external users. How you do that is dependent upon the version of TFS you've installed... which you haven't told us in your question.

Comment: I installed TFS 2017 Update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure TFS to serve the external URL. This can be done from the command line using [TFSConfig](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#settings), e.g.

```
TFSConfig Settings /ServerURL:http://100.100.100.100:10001/tfs /NotificationURL:http://100.100.100.100:10001/tfs
```

or via the Administration Console

[image: TFS Administration Console]

(screenshot is old, but still relevant).

**CAVEAT** If you expose TFS to the public internet, you should setup SSL. This is relatively easy with 2017, as they added some tools. [This page] describe the entire process (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer), but it is easier if you have your certificate at hand and setup SSL using the configuration wizard at install time.